# How does iOS app Badoo tracks second registrations?

Tags: ios, security, privacy

I've got a message from support that I cannot use the service anymore, and if I register a new profile they will automatically track it and block it. As I read from [Uber's case](https://www.theverge.com/2017/4/23/15399438/apple-uber-app-store-fingerprint-program-tim-cook-travis-kalanick) it's forbidden by Apple to track app reinstallation. So how will they track me?

1. [advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier) — I've disable it
2. Geoposition — I hope they wont block all users in my area
3. IP adress, social network profile — I've changed it
4. App Store payments I've made — if I get it right, [billing info is not visible to the developer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313548/privacy-can-a-app-from-app-store-access-my-apple-id-data?rq=1). But is it possible for developer to know if a user installed an application paid for it before?

Are there any other ways to track users?

Comment: Your understanding of the Uber case is not correct.  Apps can track users a variety of ways and you probably accept them when you agree to the app's terms of use.  Uber used geofencing to hide parts of their code from Apple's app reviewers based on their location.

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps can use the [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) API to store two bits of persistent information per device on Apple servers. This data is not cleared when an application is uninstalled; some apps may use one or both of the bits to flag devices which have already taken advantage of a free trial, or which have been blocked for abuse.

This API cannot be used to track specific devices, as it is too small to store a unique identifier. (There are only four possible values which can be stored in two bits: 00, 01, 10, and 11.)

There is no way for you to clear this data, as it is stored on Apple servers.